# Maven assembly plugin useProjectArtifact option not working in multi-module project

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to keep a module's main artifact out of the binaries copied by the assembly plug-in.
The useProjectArtifact is supposed to do exactly that, but it is not having any effect for me.

In the configuration below myGroup:myModule is one of the modules of a multi-module project, and the assembly plugin is invoked from that multi-module project.

The `<excludes>` and `<useProjectAttachments>` shouldn't be needed but even they don't help.

Looking at the debug output, it seems clear that Mavne has already copied the module artifact before even starting to process the dependency set... which makes sense, in fact I had been expecting all along that the `<useProjectArtifact>` element would appear directly in the moduleSet or binaries element (since it doesn't apply to dependencies)... however the XSD doesn't support that.

This has been driving me crazy, any suggestion would be really welcome!

Maven debug output:

```
    [DEBUG] Processing binary artifact for module project: myGroup:myModule:bundle:4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Adding artifact: myGroup:myModule:bundle:4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT with file: C:\root\myModule\target\myModule-4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to assembly location: outputdir/myModule-4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.
[DEBUG] Adding file: C:\root\myModule\target\myModule-4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to archive location: MyProject-4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/outputdir/myModule-4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[WARNING] NOTE: Currently, inclusion of module dependencies may produce unpredictable results if a version conflict occurs.
[DEBUG] Processing binary dependencies for module project: myGroup:myModule:bundle:4.1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Processing DependencySet (output=null)
[DEBUG] Filtering dependency artifacts WITHOUT transitive dependency path information.
```

Configuration:

```
 <moduleSet>
            <includes>
                <include>myGroup:myModule</include>
            </includes>

            <binaries>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>myGroup:myModule</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <outputDirectory>outputdir</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
                <dependencySets>
                    <dependencySet>
                        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
                        <useProjectAttachments>false</useProjectAttachments>
                        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*:javax.mail</include>
                        </includes>
                    </dependencySet>
                </dependencySets>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
```

Comment: Any reason not to use the maven scope "provided" in your dependencies?

Comment: Which version of Maven and maven-assembly-plugin do you use? Can you show the full assembly descriptor and not only excerts of it?

Comment: I am using maven 3.1.0 and the assembly plugin v. 2.4. There is nothing else in the descriptor but the <assembly> header and the <id>. I think I just found the answer though, see my next response.

Comment: @Aurélien Not sure what you mean, I do want javax.mail to go in the assembly so it is not "provided" but "runtime". And the problem is that the main module artifact is getting included - that isn't a dependency and AFAIK it doesn't have a scope.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that dependencySets can be used at the toplevel in an assembly, and indeed when used at that level rather than inside a moduleSet the useProjectArtifact property does what it is supposed to do.

So I am not sure whether the property is unsupported when inside a moduleSet, or whether this is a Maven defect.
I did solve my specific use case with a toplevel dependencySet, the javax.mail dependency of the module is also a dependency of the multi-module project and as a result it gets properly included in the assembly.